# Como exibir um vídeo do YouTube em um Panel no ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, youtube, extjs, panel

Gostaria de exibir um vídeo do YouTube em um Panel no ExtJS. Seria possível? Alguem pode me dar uma dica?

Comment: Qual versão do ExtJS você está usando?

Comment: @MarcoAurélio Versão 4.2.1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dê uma olhada na propriedade **html** do Panel,
que nela você pode usar o XTemplate, que se encontra nesse [link](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.2/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate)
um exemplo usando html.

O panel:

```
                xtype: 'panel',
                border: false,
                autoScroll: true,

                id:'seupanel',
                html: '\n\
                <table border="3" >\n\
                <tr>\n\
                </tr>
                </table>\n\
                ',
```

Seu Xtemplate:

```
                var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate('
                    <seu html aqui>
                );
                tpl.overwrite(panel.body, data);
```

Utilizei para mostrar html puro dentro de um panel;

Answer (score 3):

Dá uma olhada nessa extensão:

> #### [EXTJS and YouTube Integration](http://www.rclick.cz/extjs-and-youtube-integration)
>
> Pohon.ux.Youtube is package of ExtJS 3.x components which enables integration of youtube videos with your ExtJS application

Por padrão, o EXTJS não tem essa funcionalidade, mas tem essa extensão que resolve bem a questão.

Comment: Obrigado @brunosinister, vou verificar.